# Unlock device using facial recognition and go to Homescreen

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4, face-unlock

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.2 stock, and I'd like to use the facial recognition in addition to drawing an unlock-pattern. This works fine, my face is recognized, but after that, only the dots of the unlock-pattern disappear, meaning I still have to swipe the screen in order to get to the home-screen (where the icons are). I'd like to go to that screen directly when my face is recognized, without the swipe-part. So what's the clue getting rid of that? If I have to swipe, faciol recognition is useless in my opinion, because if I swipe the screen or if I swipe a pattern makes no real difference. So how is this intended to work?

Answer (score 1):

In some of the Samsung devices there is a bug in the stock rom that forces the swipe unlock to prompt even when you have by-passed your lock screen and acts as a double lock screen. This is solved if you switch to a custom ROM instead. In Some cases you want to check the lock screen tab under the settings menu and uncheck something as Use Swipe to unlock. And select the facial recognition under the settings -> Lock screen option.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Under "Lock Screen", I have the following setting options: Screen Lock -> Secured with pattern, Widget, Camera shortcut, Make Pattern Visible, lock automatically and Lock instantly with power key. But nowhere do I find a setting that says if I have to swipe or not.

Comment: You might want to find something that says: Use swipe along with pattern. It will be a checkbox. I don't have a samsung device right now or i would have told you the exact process.

PS:  It won't work on all the builds as I told you it is an bug in the firmware

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find anything like that, at least nothing that would work the way I described, i.e. unlocking by face detection without the need to swipe :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Xposed module I've just created that does what I think you're looking for:

http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.samstenner.instantunlock